# Oh-my-zsh Powerline theme terminal colors are not displaying correctly on IntelliJ

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, oh-my-zsh

I am using the Powerlevel9k theme on oh-my-zsh which looks right in the terminal (Terminator and Terminal) and Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

[image: VS Code / Terminal is similar]

In IntelliJ (Community 2018.1.5) however, the colors are inverted while the fonts seem to be working.

[image: IntelliJ]

How do I change the background and foreground colors in the IntelliJ terminal only?

Comment: Try 2018.2 from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion There were related enhancements.

Answer (score -5):

open setting/preferences > Editor > Console Fonts / Console Colors to set colors